# Dropdown behaviour issue in FireFox using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm experiencing some strange behaviour in FireFox when I'm trying to select a value in a dropdown using Selenium WebDriver. The steps I'm trying to take:

- Click open select element
- Click on item I want to select
- Click open next select element

This works perfectly in Chrome and IE. However, in FireFox, the select is clicked open (the items I can choose from are shown), the item I want to select ís clicked (get's highlighted as selected item), but when a different select element is selected and the select item is 'closed', the default value keeps showing in the select item. When I'm stepping through this piece of code in debug-mode, it works like it should! This suggested that maybe the answer could be in the time taken between steps, but experimenting with different lengths of Sleep() did not gave any result.

**To sum up:**

What I want:

- Click open select element
- Click on item I want to select
- Click open next select element

When does it work:

- Running scenario in Chrome
- Running scenario in Internet Explorer
- Stepping through scenario in FireFox

When doesn't it work:

- Running scenario in FireFox

Code that handles this part of the scenario:

```
// GetRandomValue() is a simplified representation of the code that just gives me a 
// random value from the dropdown to select
var randomDropdownValue = GetRandomValue();

Driver.FindElement(By.Id(dropdownId)).Click();

SelectElement dropdownList = new SelectElement(Driver.FindElement(By.Id(dropdownId)));
dropdownList.SelectByValue(randomDropdownValue);
```

**UPDATE**

Creating a custom FireFox profile and disabling native events did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this problem appeared to be deceveingly simple!

What I did when it didn't work:

- Click open the dropdown
- Select the element in the dropdown
- Continue to the next dropdown

What I now do what works:

- Select the element in the dropdown
- Continue to the next dropdown

I was trying to mimmick the actions of an user to much. While clicking open the dropdown before selecting the dropdownoption I wanted worked in Chrome and Internet Explorer, FireFox was 'less forgiving' and showed the 'weird' behaviour. The solution works (as far as I can see now) in every situation in FireFox, Chrome and Internet Explorer!

**Update (@aaa90210 asked for the code I use to select the element)**:

If have created a method that can be called from anywhere in my project. The stripped down version of this method is:

```
 internal static void SelectOption(OptionType optionType, string dropdownId, string option)
    {                     
        try
        {
            switch (optionType)
            {
                case OptionType.ByText:
                    new SelectElement(WebElement.Get(WebElement.Identifiers.Id, dropdownId)).SelectByText(option);
                    break;

                case OptionType.ByValue:
                    new SelectElement(WebElement.Get(WebElement.Identifiers.Id, dropdownId)).SelectByValue(option);
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {                
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for that useful tidbit of information. Removing the Click() statement from my code resolved the issue for me in Firefox as well.

Answer (score -1):

It is always better to use **WebDriverWait** rather than **sleep()**, because you wont know exactly how many seconds it'l take for the next element to appear..

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,100).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.Id("id_of_element")));
```

This code will wait until the required element is visible, if it doesnt show up even after 100 secs, an exception will be thrown..

Comment: I am aware of the existence of WebDriverWait. But it gave me some questionable results in the past, and mimicking the functionality with Sleep() and a while loop always worked. It's not the pretiest solution of them all, but it works.